# Проблема с авторизацией в SSH по ключу

Tags: linux, ssh, key

Здравствуйте, возникла такая странная  проблема: 
Есть две машины, условно сервер и клиент. Сервер работает на Ubuntu Server 16.04. клиент тоже на Ubuntu, только десктопной. Пытаюсь настроить доступ по ключу. До этого в винде настроил доступ по ключу через Bitvise SSH все работает. Ключ добавился в authorized_keys на сервере все супер. А вот с подключением клиента с линукса проблема. Создал и отправил на сервер ключ:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048
ssh-copy-id user@example.com
```

Ключ на сервере появился. На клиенте ключи тоже есть в .ssh, однако при попытке подключения командой `ssh user@example.com` все равно требует пароль. Не подскажете в чем может быть дело?

Comment: посмотрите сами или приведите строки, которые добавляются в `/var/log/auth.log` (на сервере, естественно) при попытке подключения. удобнее всего «поймать» эти строки, запустив на сервере `$ tail -n 0 -f /var/log/auth.log`, а затем попытаться подключиться с клиента.

Comment: Да, как-то совсем забыл про логи. Чуть позже прикреплю, а то у нас во Владивостоке уже ночь и клиентский компьютер уже отдыхает

Comment: Если на клиенте не один ключ, то используйте ~/.ssh/config

Comment: 1. Проверьте права на файлы ключей. 2. Бывает, что при копировании через ssh-copy-id клиент не может правильно подобрать ключ. Чтобы клиенту указать явный ключ при копировании используйте: $ ssh-copy-id -o 'IdentitiesOnly=yes' -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решает 80% проблем с ключами для меня.

Смотрим как ssh клиент пытается установить соединение:

```
ssh -v user@example.com
```

Добавляем ключи в агент на локальной машине:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/*
```

Проверяем что было добавлено:

```
ssh-add -l
```

Жестко прописываем в конфиге использовать коючи:

```
PubkeyAuthentication = yes
```

Добавляем ссылку к ключу:

```
Host example
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/example.key
```

- https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/www.cyberciti.biz/faq/force-ssh-client-to-use-given-private-key-identity-file/amp/
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-custom-connection-options-for-your-ssh-client
- https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4246809/3295105

Comment: Тянет максимум на комментарий

Comment: Нажал случайно. В процессе редактирования был. с телефона не удобно :-)

Comment: @AK, учитывая уровень вопросов на этом ресурсе — это тянет на развёрнутый ответ. +1.

Comment: @0andriy Мой комментарий был к первой версии вопроса, там пара строк была. А вы видели уже дополненную и расширенную версию. Так что оба мнения вполне корректны.